# Converting in an efficient way from string values to float values a DataFrame column with missing values

Tags: julia

I know this way to convert a column of string values to float values:

```
df = DataFrame(:a => ["2,2", "3,3"])
df.a = parse.(Float64, replace.(df.a,  (','=>'.',)))
```

But how to convert a column with missing values?

```
df = DataFrame(:a => ["2,2", missing]
```

I've tried `passmissing` but it seems not time and memory optimized:

```
julia> @time passmissing(v->parse(Float64, replace(v, (','=>'.')))).(df.a)
  0.140616 seconds (143.84 k allocations: 7.424 MiB)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.2
 3.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is optimized:

```
julia> f(x) = passmissing(v->parse(Float64, replace(v, (','=>'.'))))(x)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time f.(df.a)
  0.031789 seconds (108.92 k allocations: 5.402 MiB)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.2
 3.3

julia> @time f.(df.a)
  0.000047 seconds (11 allocations: 576 bytes)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.2
 3.3
```

The only problem that if you define a new anonymous function each time you want to do a replacement you trigger compilation anew.

If you are bound to use a new anonymous function each time then you can use a comprehension as it is lighter than broadcasting in terms of compilation cost:

```
julia> @time passmissing(v->parse(Float64, replace(v, (','=>'.')))).(df.a)
  0.051069 seconds (143.81 k allocations: 7.420 MiB)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.2
 3.3

julia> @time passmissing(v->parse(Float64, replace(v, (','=>'.')))).(df.a)
  0.072161 seconds (143.81 k allocations: 7.421 MiB)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.2
 3.3

julia> @time [passmissing(v->parse(Float64, replace(v, (','=>'.'))))(v) for v in df.a]
  0.039240 seconds (76.63 k allocations: 3.960 MiB)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.2
 3.3

julia> @time [passmissing(v->parse(Float64, replace(v, (','=>'.'))))(v) for v in df.a]
  0.051859 seconds (76.63 k allocations: 3.961 MiB, 25.99% gc time)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.2
 3.3
```

(you can see this by analyzing the volume of allocations)